# Projectile Motion Program: What's wrong with this program?

Tags: c, function

My below program does not give any values other than 0.00.

I'm new to coding, and I'm trying to apply functions. This program compiles and runs, but does not give correct values.

Any constructive comments?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define g 9.81

float MaxH(float Vi, float theta);
float ToF(float Vi, float theta);
float range(float Vi, float theta);

int main()
{
    float H=0.00, t=0.00, R=0.00, Vi, theta;

    printf("Enter initial velocity in m/s\n");
    scanf("%f", &Vi);

    printf("Enter angle Theta\n");
    scanf("%f", &theta);

    float MaxH(float Vi, float theta);
    printf("The maximum projectile height is %3.2fm\n", H);

    float ToF(float Vi, float theta);
    printf("The time of flight is %3.2fs\n ", t);

    float range(float Vi, float theta);
    printf("The horizontal range of projectile is %3.2fm\n", R);

    return 0;
}


float MaxH(float Vi, float theta)
{
    float H;

    H = (Vi*Vi*sin(theta)*sin(theta))/(2*g);

    return H;
}

float ToF(float Vi, float theta)
{
    float t;

    t = (2*Vi*sin(theta))/g;

    return t;
}

float range(float Vi, float theta)
{
    float R;

    R = (Vi*Vi*sin(2*theta))/g;

    return R;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In main(), where you want to be calling the functions with the arguments your program has accepted, you have:

```
float MaxH(float Vi, float theta);
float ToF(float Vi, float theta);
float range(float Vi, float theta);
```

These are actually just redeclaring the function signatures. To actually call the functions you want to use correct syntax and assign the output to your variables, so you can print them:

```
H = MaxH(Vi, theta);
t = ToF(Vi, theta);
R = range(Vi, theta);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not calling the function anywhere you are declaring the function again
`float MaxH(float Vi, float theta);`.

function calling will be like `H = MaxH(Vi, theta);` and follow the same for other functions.